# In Ember how to exclude single from vendor folder from minifying

Tags: ember.js, babeljs, ember-cli

I got situation like, I included `morris.js` file from vendor folder, and configured in `ember-cli-build.js` file but then my specific modified feature is working in development but not in the production build.

I am using [ember-cli-babili](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-babili) for minification. either I should fix which minification part causing the issue or I should remove this file alone from minification.

Is this possible? any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [it is possible](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#exclude-from-minification)!

```
// ember-cli-build.js
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    minifyJS: {
      options: {
        exclude: ["**/morris.js"]
      }
    }
  });

  //...
  return app.toTree();
};
```